# SQL insert ID from IDENTITY ID of the row being inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, scope-identity

I would like to know, if there is a direct way to insert ID (generated at ID column with IDENTITY(1,1)) to another columns.
In another words, I am looking for SCOPE_IDENTITY() I could get *at the time of inserting*, not *after* the INSERT is commited.

I have a table, where there is a column with secondary ID (SID), which references rows from the same table and in some special cases it references itself.
The only way I know to do that is to do the INSERT and consequently UPDATE SID in those cases. Simplified example:

```
DECLARE @ID INT
INSERT INTO Table (SID) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
UPDATE Table SET SID = ID WHERE ID = @ID;
```

There are some glitches, i.e. due to the fact that the row may or may not reference itself, etc.

Comment: your question is unclear. What is wrong with the INSERT/UPDATE scenario?

Comment: It works, but makes the script longer with a risk of error, especially, because the example is simplified and there are cases to be distinguished.

Comment: One way to reduce risk of errors, is to go with Sequences. Look it up.

Comment: @Oak_3260548 wrap it in single transaction if you are aware of errors.

Comment: I agree, it is wrapped in a single transaction already. I have to use insert+update in this case due to the fact, that one "SID" column may have valid NULL values. In other cases AFTER INSERT trigger seems to be a fine solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. In case of self-reference, leave the column NULL and have the trigger set the column equal to the IDENTITY column.

In pseudo:

- Join the table with `inserted`, filter where SID is NULL
- For those rows, update the table and set `SID = ID`

---

If it is not possible to use the NULL value, in cases where it should be possible to have no reference at all, you can use another stub value. E.g. -1 if the IDs will always be positive. In that case, apply the above way of working and substitute NULL with -1.

Comment: Since there are no other answers, I consider it the only solution to avoid the procedure described in my question, so I marked it as an answer. I can use it in some cases, though not in this particular case, because one of the "SID" columns (there are more then 1) may be NULL (have no refference).

Comment: @Oak_3260548 That is tough, I don't really see any other way. Perhaps you could use a stub value other than NULL for self-referencing? E.g. the minimum value of INT (-2,147,483,648)?

Comment: Yes, that came to my mind right after I posted the comment. I could simply use i.e. (-1) value, since my IDs are obviously always positive... It would be great if you add this case into your answer for future references for other users.